# Django templates foreign key traversal

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys

I saw multiple questions on this but non worked for me, so I'll query about my specific issue
I have a table with several foreign keys pointing to other tables, looks like:

```
class EventCodes(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Severities(models.Model):
    severity_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Systems(models.Model):
    system_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Events(models.Model):
    system_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(Systems)
    severity_fk = models.ForeignKey(Severities)
    code_fk = models.ForeignKey(EventCodes)
```

I also have a template that allows a user to define a search criteria per system_id and/or severity_name and/or code_name -> this will give me the relevant records from the Events table

The only problem is that now when I present them in the results template I present their IDs and not their values (the Django ORM added the id PK for each of these tables)

QUESTION: How do i allow the results html which got the queryset of the Events to access the values on the System, Severities, EventCodes tables so I can present their string value and not their non human readable ID

Answer (score 1):

You can span relationships by accessing the property by using`.` [Django covers this in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships)

```
an_event = Events.objects.all()[0]
an_event.system_id_fk.system_id
```

---

Your naming convention could be a little confusing because for ForeignKey Fields django automatically creates an `_id` field on the model:

```
system_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(Systems)
```

The above creates a column named `system_id_fk_id` in the `events` table in your db.  But when you access `an_event.system_id_fk` it will use the `system_id_fk_id` column to query the related objeCT!!!

Comment: That I know and already use for creating the initial filtering, question is once i pass the queryset (of the Events table) to the html template, how does the html template traverse the foreign key {{ event.system_id_fk_id.system_id }} does not do it

Comment: in your example: `{{ event.system_id_fk_id.system_id }}` should be `{{ event.system_id_fk.system_id }}`, thats what i was trying to say `system_id_fk_id` is just an integer, not the related object, you can use `system_id_fk` to access the related object

Comment: OK, I stand corrected {{ event.system_id_fk.system_id }} - did the job. I am a bit confused now. Django added the _id at the end of the foreign keys, how come i need to disregard it in order to access it?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was the point I seem to have missed all day